# How do I avoid lots of checking in Java?

Tags: java

When writing a Java program, I face a problem as follows:

```
Map<Object, Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>>> map = new HashMap<>();
/**
* put operations
**/
Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>> a = null;
Map<Object, Object> b = null;
Object c = null;
a = map.get(/*some object*/);
if(a != null) {
    b = a.get(/*some object*/);
}
if(b != null) {
    c = b.get(/*some object*/);
}
if(c != null) {
    /*do what I want to do*/
}
```

If I want to be sure `c` is not `null`, I need to add an "if" three times to ensure that the code can run without exception. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Move the 2 if's inside their parent. No need to continue as soon as the one before it fails.

Comment: What are you trying to represent? Collections that deeply nested usually suggest you should be extracting classes to represent the intermediate values.

Comment: Crate a class and write your own `get` method to check this conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the [getOrDefault](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-)-method of the `Map` interface could work here. Especially if you combine it with the [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class as follows:

```
Map<Object, Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>> a = map.getOrDefault("", Collections.emptyMap());
Map<Object, Object> b = a.getOrDefault("", Collections.emptyMap());
Optional.ofNullable(b.get("")).ifPresent(c -> {/* Do what I want to do */});
```

This way you simply use `getOrDefault` to retrieve empty maps (which I personally like better than `null` values. The `Optional.ofNullable` is a `null`-safe way of creating an `Optional` object and you can *do what you want to do* in the lambda expression.

Both `Optional` and `Map.getOrDefault` are part of Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate required functionality in a class implementing something like this:

```
interface ThreeKeysMap {
    void put(Object keyA, Object keyB, Object keyC, Object value);
    Object get(Object keyA, Object keyB, Object keyC);
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a class for your composite key:

```
public class ThreeKey {
    public Object keyA;
    public Object keyB;
    public Object keyC;

    // TODO: MUST override equals and hashCode methods or map won't work!!!!
}
```

and use it as a key for your map: `Map<ThreeKey, Object> map = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class `Key<T,E>` that will hold your first pairs of objects, and than create a map

```
Map<Key<T,E>, Object>
```

This seems much more neat to me, because it seems you use the first two objects as a key, and the nested dictionary approach is less elegant for such a task.

Remember that if you follow this approach - you have to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`, and depending on usages - sometimes also `compareTo()`